# Firefox uninstallation in RHEL5.8

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, firefox

I am facing one issue while uninstalling firefox on RHEL 5.8, Please find my work round below suggest to uninstall firefox package completely.

```
[root@dev170app ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

[root@dev170app ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i firefox
firefox-3.6.26-1.0.1.el5_7
firefox-3.6.26-1.0.1.el5_7

[root@dev170app ~]# rpm -e firefox-3.6.26-1.0.1.el5_7
error: "firefox-3.6.26-1.0.1.el5_7" specifies multiple packages

[root@dev170app ~]# rpm -e firefox-3.6.26-1.0.1.el5_7 --nodeps
error: "firefox-3.6.26-1.0.1.el5_7" specifies multiple packages


[root@dev170app ~]# rpm -e firefox --allmatches (Hanging)

[root@dev170app ~]#yum remove firefox (Hanging)
```

After executing above two command process is sticking and it is not completing and I did wait for more than 24 hours. Please suggest to remove firefox completely.

Comment: What does 'yum check' say ?

Comment: There's a chance that `yum remove` hangs because the repos have gone by now. That should give you a timeout error message after 30 seconds or so, I don't know how long without reaction is "hanging" for you.

Answer (score 0):

I will add the architecture of the package .

example :

```
# rpm --queryformat '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n' -qa bc\*
bc-1.06.95-1.el6.x86_64
# rpm -e bc-1.06.95-1.el6.x86_64
#
```